# IIS hosted WCF-service + Windows auth in IIS + TransportCredentialOnly/Windows auth in basicHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, iis

I want to create a WCF-service hosted in IIS6 and disable anonymous authentication in IIS. And don't use SSL.

So only way I have is to use basicHttpBinging with `TransportCredentialOnly`, itsn't it?

I create a virtual directory, set Windows Integrated Auth and uncheck "Enable Anonymous Access".

Here's my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="MyBinding">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="Samples.ServiceFacadeService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceFacadeServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingName="MyBinding"
                          contract="Samples.IServiceFacadeService">
                </endpoint>
            </service>
        </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceFacadeServiceBehavior">
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

You can see that I even haven't included MEX-enpoint for metadata exchange. Just one endpoint and one binding for it with TransportCredentialOnly security.

But when I tries to start service (invoking a method throught client proxy) I got such exception in the EventLog:

> Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException:
>   The service
>   '/wcftest/ServiceFacadeService.svc'
>   cannot be activated due to an
>   exception during compilation.  The
>   exception message is: Security
>   settings for this service require
>   'Anonymous' Authentication but it is
>   not enabled for the IIS application
>   that hosts this service.. --->
>   System.NotSupportedException: Security
>   settings for this service require
>   'Anonymous' Authentication but it is
>   not enabled for the IIS application
>   that hosts this service.

I have no idea why my service require Anonymous auth? Why?

Answer (score 8):

The answer found jezell. Thanks.
I mixed up bindingName and bindingConfiguration :

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingName="MyBinding"
          contract="Samples.IServiceFacadeService">
</endpoint>
```

That's right:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" **bindingConfiguration**="MyBinding"
          contract="Samples.IServiceFacadeService">
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score 7):

The MEX endpoint may still be the problem (see this [post](http://ahmed0192.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!FD6F44C91F5D2AD9!160.entry)). Try disabling MEX like this:

```
<services>
    <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
    <service name="MyNamespace.MyServiceType" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
        <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
        <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
    </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
            <!-- This disables it. -->
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Here is a good [post](http://www.leastprivilege.com/SecuringWCFMetadata.aspx) on securing MEX.

Comment: I don't have MEX endpoint at all. Securing of mex-endpoint is another challenge. But I agree not to have it at all. I guess it's no point in setting httpGetEnabled to false if I haven't got mex-endpoint. Anyway, this haven't helped, I tried.

Comment: I think that WCF automatically sets up a default MEX endpoint. The suggestion I made was to manually create the MEX endpoint which overrides the default and disable it to prevent the compilation step from detecting the requirement to have anonymous access for the MEX endpoint.

Comment: Interesting. But everything got worked without mex-endpoint after I fixed my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Use basicHttpBinding for your mex endpoint and apply the same bindingConfiguration:

Answer (score 1):

To get VS wcf service project (new sample project) to work with authentication under IIS, you have to:

1) Allow Anonymous access in IIS
2) Prefix your public methods with a attribute like this:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "MyADGroup")]
public string SendMyMessage(string Message)
{...}
```