# Cannot get Metadata with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I am trying to set a web services that return JSON objects and I was following this [tutorial](http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page1.htm) but when I go try to run it I get this error

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from `http://localhost:10995/Service1.svc`
>   If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you
>   have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at
>   the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please
>   refer to the MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI: `http://localhost:10995/Service1.svc`    Metadata contains
>   a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'localhost:10995/Service1.svc'.    The remote server returned
>   an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.    The remote server
>   returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.HTTP GET Error    URI:
>   `http://localhost:10995/Service1.svc`    There was an error downloading
>   `http://localhost:10995/Service1.svc`.    The request failed with HTTP
>   status 404: Not Found.

So I tried looking up what that means and came across these links to try to fix it

[WCF - Cannot obtain Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361013/wcf-cannot-obtain-metadata)

[WCF - Error: Cannot obtain Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192824/wcf-error-cannot-obtain-metadata)

[Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056329/error-cannot-obtain-metadata-from-wcf-service)

[WCF Test Client cannot add service, cannot obtain metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114870/wcf-test-client-cannot-add-service-cannot-obtain-metadata)

but none of them fixed the problem. This is my first attempt at doing any sort of web service stuff and I literally started researching today so obviously I am new to all of this.

what does this error mean and how can I fix it so I can test it out?

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WcfService4.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService4.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="../Service1.svc"
      binding="webHttpBinding"
      contract="WcfService4.IService1"
      behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfService4.Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehaviour">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Check you endpoint address,behavior configuration and contract name properly.

Comment: So no upvoted answer or green tick.. Any idea what can solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

its not just a typo is it?

```
contract="WcfService4e.IService1"
```

is it supposed to be

```
contract="WcfService4.IService1"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> use  namespace name with your service name and contract name... See
>   the code snippet below:

```
<service name="WcfService3.Service1"
 behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
>         
<endpoint address="../Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1">
```

where **"WcfService3"** is the namespcae.